# Does the reputation reward system lead to overfitting?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-experience

I see aggressive tagging of new questions with "This question already has an answer here:" when the questions are often relatively distinct.

The corrective tagging may link to a somewhat-associated concept, but my feeling is this behavior robs the site of a fuller variety of specific examples mated with direct solutions. It also discourages newer users whether searching or posting.

If we change the metrics to disincentivize excessive corrections like this, wouldn't the site grow with quality content?

Comment: Please be specific -- show an example of what you mean, since closing questions as duplicates is one of the distinct benefits of the site. Do we really want to encourage thousands more Java NullPointerException questions than we already have?

Answer (score 24):

There are literally *zero* incentives to identify or mark duplicates, aside from an intrinsic motivation to keep the site’s content accessible and consolidated.

If anything, there is a perverse disincentive: the reputation system, as you mentioned. Answering a new duplicate question can net you rep from upvotes, whereas marking it as a duplicate nets you bupkis.

Furthermore, your proposal is missing a critical justification for why, exactly, having a question marked as a duplicate would ever be discouraging for new users. Instead of “here, try this, I think it might work”, you get a link to time-tested solutions vetted by experts. And, if anything, the lack of friction involved in posting duplicate questions serves to disincentivize askers from searching first, before asking and letting others do the research to find the relevant duplicates.

Comment: I think this question was about *incorrect* duplicates, because OP mentions *"... when the questions are often relatively distinct"*. If the duplicate is accurate and contains a good answer, then yes, it is good for OP.

Comment: Well, sure, incorrect duplicates are not useful for anyone. That's not a reason to throw the baby out with the bathwater. That's why we allow people to reopen.